Designing a Generic IInboxRepository for Modular ASP.NET Application with Multiple DbContexts
I'm building a modular application using ASP.NET 8 and implementing the inbox/outbox pattern for communication between modules. Here's my scenario:

Module A receives an integration event.
I want to store this event in the database using a generic IInboxRepository.
Each module has its own DbContext for its specific data.

How can I design my IInboxRepository to resolve the correct DbContext and save the integration event in the appropriate inbox table for the originating module?
Here is my current approach, but I'm not satisfied with it and I'm unsure why:
public interface IDbContext
{
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public interface IInboxRepository<T>
    where T : IDbContext
{
    Task AddAndSaveAsync(IIntegrationEvent integrationEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public sealed class GenericIntegrationEventHandler<TEvent, TDbContext>(
    IInboxRepository<TDbContext> inboxRepository)
    : IIntegrationEventHandler<TEvent>
    where TEvent : class, IIntegrationEvent
    where TDbContext : IDbContext
{
    private readonly IInboxRepository<TDbContext> _inboxRepository = inboxRepository;

    public async Task Handle(TEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _inboxRepository.AddAndSaveAsync(notification, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public sealed class InboxRepository<T>(T dbContext)
    : IInboxRepository<T>
    where T : IDbContext
{
    private readonly T _dbContext = dbContext;

    public async Task AddAndSaveAsync(IIntegrationEvent integrationEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}

Questions:

How can I design the IInboxRepository to dynamically resolve the correct DbContext for each module and save the event?
Are there any improvements or alternative approaches to achieve this in a more elegant and efficient way?

I highly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance!

Worth a read - Outbox, Inbox patterns explained.
